# JavaFX Only 1 part of SimpleStringProperty showing up on TableView

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to put a SimpleStringProperty on a TableView this is the class im using:

```
    package com.launch.history;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import com.launch.WebController;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class HistoryController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableView<HistoryClient> tableView;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<HistoryClient, String> tableColumn;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        setTableView();
    }

    public void setColumns() {
        tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<HistoryClient, String>("history"));
    }

    public void setTableView() {
        tableView.setItems(getHistory());
        setColumns();
        tableView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() >= 0) {
                    HistoryClient link = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                    WebController.engine.load(link.getHistory());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public ObservableList<HistoryClient> getHistory() {
        ObservableList<HistoryClient> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        data.addAll(new HistoryClient());
        return data;
    }
}
```

And this is the the stuff about history:

```
public static String getHistory() {
        return history.get();
    }

    public static void setHistory(String history) {
        HistoryClient.history.set(history);
    }

    private static SimpleStringProperty history = new SimpleStringProperty();
```

But i only get 1 line on my TableView(The last link)

And this is how i set the value of history:

```
public static void readHistory() {
        if(Files.HISTORY_FILE.exists()) {
            try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Files.HISTORY_FILE))) {
                String line;
                while( (line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    history.set(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

That works fine i printed out history and it was the same as in the file so i really don't see the problem because last time when i used TableView i kinda did the same thing.

And yes i did set the fx:id in scene builder.

Comment: You have lots of errors in this. For example, the types of the table view (`String`) and column (`HistoryClient`) don't match. You haven't shown where you add the column to the table (though you may have done it in FXML). You set a cell value factory on the table column, but the type of the table view is `String`, which certainly doesn't define either a `historyProperty()` or a `getHistory()` method. I recommend you read the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#CJAGAAEE) and work from there.

Comment: Thank you! but now it's only displaying 1 link.

Comment: Your `getHistory()` method (in `HistoryController`) only creates one `HistoryClient`. So of course there is only one row in the table. The rest of your code is not really clear to me. Is that the `HistoryClient` class? If so, why is the property `static`?